Access AWS data catalog Iceberg and Non-iceberg tables from local spark session
I want to read data from AWS data catalog tables(Iceberg and Non-Iceberg) from pyspark code in local environment.
I have configured the SparkSession accordingly. While I am able to access the Iceberg tables from local, the non-Iceberg tables are not showing up.
I have used the following sparksession configuration:
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')) \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')) \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token", os.getenv('AWS_SESSION_TOKEN')) \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", f"s3.{os.getenv('AWS_REGION')}.amazonaws.com") \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.region", os.getenv('AWS_REGION')) \
            .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.6.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.4,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.874,software.amazon.awssdk:bundle:2.27.2,software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.27.2,software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.27.2,software.amazon.awssdk:glue:2.27.2") \
            .config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog') \
            .config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog') \
            .config('spark.sql.iceberg.handle-timestamp-without-timezone', 'true') \
            .config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse', 's3://glue/datalake/') \
            .config('spark.sql.extensions','org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions')\
            .config('spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO') \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
            .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "s3://glue") \
            .enableHiveSupport() \
            .getOrCreate()

For Non-Iceberg tables I am getting the following error:
[TABLE_OR_VIEW_NOT_FOUND].
If you could kindly look into this and help resolve the issue.
I am expecting to be able to access both iceberg and non-iceberg catalog tables using the same spark session in my local environment.

any luck? I am facing the same issue
